# Как добавить в DataGridView информацию из нескольких таблиц или как подключить представление к DGV?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server

Существует таблица "Заказ" с разными полями, три из которых - идентификаторы-ключи на другие таблицы, требуется заменить IDшники на ФИО людей, соответствующих данным ID.
Как подключить представление (в котором уже написан корректный запрос) к DGV-таблице в Windows Form? Либо как направить данные из нескольких таблиц вместо представления?

Представление:

```
SELECT dbo.Заказ.IDзаказа, dbo.Курьер.ФИО AS ФИОкурьера, dbo.Клиент.ФИО AS ФИОклиента, dbo.Адресат.ФИО AS ФИОадресата, dbo.Заказ.НомерЗаказа, dbo.Заказ.Вес, dbo.Заказ.МанипуляционныйЗнак, 
       dbo.Заказ.Комментарий, dbo.Заказ.ВидДоставки, dbo.Заказ.ДатаОформления, dbo.Заказ.ДатаИсполнения
FROM dbo.Заказ
INNER JOIN dbo.Курьер ON dbo.Заказ.IDкурьера = dbo.Курьер.IDкурьера
INNER JOIN dbo.Клиент ON dbo.Заказ.IDклиента = dbo.Клиент.IDклиента
INNER JOIN dbo.Адресат ON dbo.Заказ.IDадресата = dbo.Адресат.IDадресата
```

(в исх. таблице вместо ФИО курьера, адресата и клиента - IDшники)

Comment: [Руководство](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Замените sql-запрос на свой.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, разобралась!